# JNI/NDK set list attribute in java object from c++

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Is there a possibility to set a list attribute in an java object from c++? I can access the list but i don't no how to set the field.

I can write a setter or an addElement function but that is not my intention.

ContentStruct.java:

```
public class ContentStruct {
    public List<Integer> codeWidth = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public List<String> format = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

main.cpp:

```
typedef struct{
public:
    std::vector<int> codeWidth;
    std::vector<std::string> format;
}contentStruct;

JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_package_MainActivity_function(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz){

    contentStruct cs;

    //fillCS(cs);

    jclass jContentStruct = env->FindClass(".../ContentStruct");
    jmethodID constructor = env->GetMethodID(jContentStruct, "<init>", "()V");
    jobject instance_CS = env->NewObject(jContentStruct, constructor);
    jfieldID f_codeHeight = env->GetFieldID(jContentStruct, "codeHeight", "Ljava/util/List;");
    //env->SetObjectField(instance_CS, f_codeHeight, cs.codeHeight);
}
```

Comment: You'd have to create a java.util.List in your C++ code and populate it with the data you want it to contain. It's unclear from your question exactly what part of that that you're having trouble with.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're trying to do.  If you're trying to set an attritbute on a `List`, what `List` attribute do you want to set?  A `List` is a container for things - it doesn't really have attributes independent of what it contains.  *I can write a setter or an addElement function but that is not my intention.*  OK, so what *is* your intention?

Comment: Ok, i have for example codeWidth filled in c++. Now i want to set the vector codeWidth to the java field codeWith. Pseudocode: ``java.ContentStruct.codeWidth = C++.cs.codeWidth``

Comment: than you just need to get `add(Object)` method from that list class and use it. `List` in native code does not have template type, so remember what type of items you want to have in that list (remember of boxing, etc)

Comment: Your `SetObjectField` is what you need except you cannot assign your vector directly. You have to do what Michael said and first create an ArrayList object with your data in it in your C code.